# Is there any difference between FHT and FWHT?

Tags: image-processing, orthogonal

I have two questions:

1. I need to know that is there any difference between the terms Fast Hadamard Transform (FHT) and Fast Walsh-Hadamard Transform (FWHT) ?
   Can i use these two terms interchangeably ?
2. By a Normalized FHT, do we mean dividing all the values of output matrix (after doing FHT on data) by the largest value in the output matrix ?
   What is the physical significance of a Normalized Transform ? (for e.g., Normalized FHT)

regards.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia it looks the same:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform

Up to the normalization factor.

And indeed there's an efficient implementation using the same trick in the FFT algorithm.